# Seaborn cluster heatmap

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, seaborn

I am getting familiar with Seaborn and I am trying to create a cluster heatmap. Examples work, but I don't quite get what is going on.

Let us suppose I have the points  `P1, P2, P3, P4` which have features `x0, x1,...,x9`. This means that each `P` data point lives in the 10 dimensional feature space. When I do clustering on these data points, I would expect to compute distances (euclidean or other) in this 10 dimensional space and carry out the clustering based on these distances. The output should be the grouping of `P1, ... P4`.

Then there is seaborn's `clustermap` function which says that it takes the rectangular data, carries out the clustering and represents it on a clustermap. However, what I see is that it carries out the clustering along both axis. Instead of having a grouping of points `P` only, it carries out a grouping of features `x` as well:

[image: Clustering of points and features]

What I would have expected was a square map with diagonal symmetry, with points on both axes, and coloring according to the distances between those points. Here I don't get what the coloring represents. Using `clustermap(df.corr())` instead of `clustermap(df)` would give the right shape, but that's not what I need since I want to use custom distances and definitely don't want to use the correlation matrix as features.

So my question is how to get the symmetric square clustermap that is colored according to the distance metric I provide to `clustermap`?

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

#--- Set up a dataframe with features on rows and points in columns.
#--- Here each point is in the 10 dimensional space
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4'])
df.columns.name = 'points'
for i in range(10):
    df = df.append(pd.Series(data= np.random.randn(4), index=df.columns), ignore_index=True)
df['features'] = (['x'+str(i) for i in range(10)])
df = df.set_index('features')


#--- Construct clustermap out of the data
cg = sns.clustermap(df)
pl.show()

#--- This is the right shape, but how are distances calculated?
cg = sns.clustermap(df.corr())
pl.show()
```

Comment: The heatmap is showing the values in the matrix you provide. The clustering organizes the rows and columns to bring out structure in the matrix. It sounds like you want to do something completely different. Maybe look at the `scipy.distance` module?